# How to update application context from database in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I want to read some configuration value from  application context in spring boot application. But I  want this value should be update from database when my application is initialized

There will be a function which will refresh  the data in application context from the database .

Basically I want to update data from database  in application context after its initialization has been done.

Comment: You can create the db Connection with a Bean and annotate the function with @postcreate

Comment: Can you add some code

Comment: @MedTech  thank your reply can you explain with some example

Comment: @AjitSoman  recently i got a requirement from my client and it is in discussion mode requirement currently we have some  configuration in properties  file  in static mode  now we are planing to move it in database  and we will read it from context and context will update from database in time of initialization

Comment: @AmbarGupta, I understood , You can check for `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)`. The method annotated with this annotation will be trigger at the start of server. You can then make a db call and save object in a global variable and use it for further use.